# Can I have same upnp device with different description/services during run time?

Tags: upnp, discovery

While going through upnp spec I got the following doubts .
Can I define a basic upnp device with all mandatory fields and with no servicelist and 
when providing the description xml I will modify my description xml to advertise my service based to different conditions.
eg: services may playmusic OR switch light OR playfootball.

**Can i modify the xml per device basis on run time to inlcude completely different and random services?**

I hope the description and service xmls are not static .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like almost everything else in UPnP Device Arch document this is not 100% clearly defined, but the idea of dynamic device/service descriptions is mentioned:

> If a device needs to
>   change one of these descriptions, it MUST cancel its outstanding
>   advertisements and re-advertise. Consequently, control points SHOULD
>   NOT assume that device and service descriptions are unchanged if a
>   device re-appears on the network, but they can detect whether
>   descriptions changed if a changed CONFIGID.UPNP.ORG field value is
>   present in the announcements.

So descriptions are not static, but you do need need to cancel and re-advertize.

That said, abusing this does not sound useful (Why not use separate root devices or at least sub-devices for totally unrelated services) and is bound to lead to compatibility issues.